# dropdownlist server side event not called when client side event is also defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

There is a `dropdownlist` and an `ImageButton` in a `.aspx` page. When user selects the country Australia, There is the need to show an ImageButton ( a Flag Image), which takes the user to its respective website on clicking it. Rest other websites  are internally hosted so no need to display Image Button.

There is a Client side as well as server side event defined for the dropdownlist.

Problem is that the server side event of this dropdownlist : `OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSortBy_SelectedIndexChanged"`  is not getting called. What went wrong ?

Also, as observed when the Client side event is removed, then Server side event is getting called. Why so ?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountries" runat="server"
     AutoPostBack="true" onchange="return ddlCountriesSelected();"
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountries_IndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Text="_Select_" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Australia"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Spain"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="England"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="India"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Germany"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:ImageButton ID="CountriesImage" runat="server" />
```

Client side:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" >
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function ddlCountriesSelected() {
     var ddlCntrs = document.getElementById('<%=ddlCountries.ClientID %>');
     // alert(ddlCntrs.selectedIndex); // debug purpose
     if (ddlCntrs.selectedIndex == "1")
      {
        var img = document.getElementById('<%=CountriesImage.ClientID%>');
        img.src ='Images/'+ddlCntrs.options[ddlCntrs.selectedIndex].value+'.png';
        return true; 
       }
       else 
        {
           // code to hide the ImageButton
           return false;
        }    
        } 
       </script>
 ...
...
</body>
```

// Code Behind

```
protected void ddlCountries_IndexChanged(object sender,System.EventArgs e)
    {
        lbl1.Text = ddlCountries.SelectedValue;
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of _ddlCntrs_ ?

Comment: ddlCntrs just gets the dropdownlist control. Is there any issue you notice. Please let me know

Answer (score 2):

hope following code will solve your problem -

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountries" runat="server"
 AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountries_IndexChanged" 
 onchange="ddlCountriesSelected();">
<asp:ListItem Text="_Select_" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Australia"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Spain"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="England"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="India"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Germany"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:ImageButton ID="CountriesImage" runat="server" />
```

Client side:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" >
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function ddlCountriesSelected() {
     var ddlCntrs = document.getElementById('<%=ddlCountries.ClientID %>');
     // alert(ddlCntrs.selectedIndex); // debug purpose
     if (ddlCntrs.selectedIndex == "1")
      {
        var img = document.getElementById('<%=CountriesImage.ClientID%>');
        img.src ='Images/'+ddlCntrs.options[ddlCntrs.selectedIndex].value+'.png';
       // return true; 
       }
       else 
        {
           // code to hide the ImageButton
          // return false;
        }    
    } 
   </script>
 ...
...
</body>
```

// backend code

```
protected void ddlCountries_IndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    lbl1.Text = ddlCountries.SelectedValue;

}
```

make sure to add label also.. :D

Comment: I had returned true also in both cases ( if and else). But no success. Even i just removed the conditions altogether and just returned true from the function, again No success.

Comment: I have checked the code. I found that there is 2 main issues in your code - 
1 - on backend code correct the dropdownlist name.
2 - in javascript correct imagebutton name.

I am editing my answer which is working fine at my side.

Answer (score 0):

Here I suggest you to check the return value of "ddlCountriesSelected" function.
If this  returns false, in that case also DropDownList  control will not be able to post the page on to the server.
Try returning "True" in both conditions by java script function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ddlCountriesSelected() {

  var ddlCntrs = document.getElementById('<%=ddlCountries.ClientID %>');

  if (ddlCntrs.selectedIndex == "1")
  {
      var img = document.getElementById('<%=ImageButton1.ClientID%>');
      img.src ='Images/'+ddlCntrs.options[ddlCntrs.selectedIndex].value+'.png';
      return true; 
  }
  else 
  {
      // code to hide the ImageButton
      return true;
  }    
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Tried returning true in every case but still no success. Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have one another idea for you.
Please remove "onchange" event of dropdown control.
In addition I suggest you to set "src" of Image control on server in "ddlCountries_IndexChanged" event handler.

Comment: Ok. But any reason why the above setup doesn't works. I want to avoid unnecessary postbacks

Comment: Yes, there is a strong reason behind it, you were using "onchange"  & "OnSelectedIndexChanged" both events at a time, while "onchange" event works after rendering dropdownlist control ( or should  say that it work with html select) and "OnSelectedIndexChanged" event also converted into "onchange" event after rendering. that is why your page was not being post back. your "OnSelectedIndexChanged" event was override by "onchange" after rendering. I believe, now it is clear to you   :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do following modification in your client side and server side code,so that it may be work

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" >
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function ddlCountriesSelected() {
     var ddlCntrs = document.getElementById('<%=ddlCountries.ClientID %>');
     // alert(ddlCntrs.selectedIndex); // debug purpose
     if (ddlCntrs.selectedIndex == "1")
      {
        var img = document.getElementById('<%=CountriesImage.ClientID%>');
        img.src ='Images/'+ddlCntrs.options[ddlCntrs.selectedIndex].value+'.png';
     return true; 
       }
       else 
        {
           // code to hide the ImageButton
         return true;
        }    
    } 
   </script>
```

...
...

//Server side code

```
protected void ddlCountries_IndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    lbl1.Text = ddlCountries.SelectedValue;

}
```